# Why is postfix rejecting one particular validly DNS-mapped sender?

Tags: postfix, connections

I'm running postfix 3.5.18 under Debian 11. The mailserver is working fine for all senders except one.

I regularly am getting this message from emails from one sender and one sender only  (where I changed a valid email address on my server to "user@myexample.com" in the message, and where I changed the server name in that message to MYEXAMPLE) ...

```
Jul 15 17:05:45 MYEXAMPLE postfix/smtpd[350738]: Anonymous TLS connection established from smtp3.earlywarning.com[199.47.137.176]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jul 15 17:05:46 MYEXAMPLE postfix/smtpd[350738]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from smtp3.earlywarning.com[199.47.137.176]: 450 4.7.1 <a7283cpov.earlywarning.com>: Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<consumerservices@earlywarning.com> to=<user@myexample.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<a7283cpov.earlywarning.com>
Jul 15 17:06:02 MYEXAMPLE postfix/smtpd[350738]: timeout after RSET from smtp3.earlywarning.com[199.47.137.176]
Jul 15 17:06:02 MYEXAMPLE postfix/smtpd[350738]: disconnect from smtp3.earlywarning.com[199.47.137.176] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 commands=5/7
```

The "earlywarning.com" and "smtp3.earlywarning.com" hostnames are validly mapped in DNS.

The following is the output of "postconf -n", with my hostname changed to MYEXAMPLE.COM, and my IP address changed to AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD ...

```
address_verify_poll_count = ${stress?1}${stress:3}
address_verify_sender = postmaster@$myhostname
address_verify_sender_ttl = 1342s
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
disable_dns_lookups = no
double_bounce_sender = double-bounce
hippomda_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
message_size_limit = 199999999
milter_command_timeout = 20s
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v {client_name} {client_addr} {client_port}
milter_connect_timeout = 10s
milter_mail_macros = {auth_author} {auth_type} {auth_authen}
milter_protocol = 6
minimal_backoff_time = 60s
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = MYEXAMPLE.COM
mynetworks = AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/32
myorigin = MYEXAMPLE.COM
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
queue_run_delay = 60s
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = -
relay_domains =
relayhost =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
smtp_host_lookup = dns
smtp_skip_5xx_greeting = no
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_block_early_mail_reply = yes
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls-control
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_banner = Abandon hope, all ye who enter here.
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/ok-host-control check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo-control reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 2s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = ${stress?2}${stress:4}
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/ok-host-control check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo-control permit_sasl_authenticated reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_junk_command_limit = ${stress?3}${stress:50}
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:20002,local:opendkim/opendkim.sock,local:opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
smtpd_per_record_deadline = ${stress?yes}${stress:no}
smtpd_recipient_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_overshoot_limit = 100
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/reject-impossible-address.pcre reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_unverified_recipient permit_dnswl_client list.dnswl.org=127.0.[0..255].[1..3] permit_sasl_authenticated reject_non_fqdn_recipient
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/ok-host-control reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 2
smtpd_starttls_timeout = ${stress?5}${stress:12}s
smtpd_timeout = ${stress?5}${stress:12}s
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYEXAMPLE.COM/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYEXAMPLE.COM/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = low
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ADH-AES256-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ADH-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:NULL-SHA256
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport-control
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:1003
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_transport = hippomda
virtual_uid_maps = static:1003
```

Here are the "helo-control" file contents:

```
earlywarning.com    OK
.earlywarning.com   OK
199.47.137.176      OK
104.18.100.92       OK
104.18.99.92        OK
```

And here are the contents of the "ok-host-control" file ...

```
earlywarning.com    OK
.earlywarning.com   OK
199.47.137.176      OK
104.18.100.92       OK
104.18.99.92        OK
```

Both "helo-control" and "ok-host-control" are properly mapped to "helo-control.db" and "ok-host-control.db", respectively, via "postconf -f".

What am I doing wrong which causes connections from "smtp3.earlywarning.com[199.47.137.176]" to be rejected?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

Postmap test ...

```
# postmap -v -q 'a7283cpov.earlywarning.com' ./ok-host-control; echo rc=$?
postmap: name_mask: all
postmap: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv4 addresses
postmap: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv6 addresses
postmap: Compiled against Berkeley DB: 5.3.28?
postmap: Run-time linked against Berkeley DB: 5.3.28?
postmap: dict_open: hash:./ok-host-control
rc=1

# postmap -v -q 'a7283cpov.earlywarning.com' ./helo-control; echo rc=$?
postmap: name_mask: all
postmap: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv4 addresses
postmap: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv6 addresses
postmap: Compiled against Berkeley DB: 5.3.28?
postmap: Run-time linked against Berkeley DB: 5.3.28?
postmap: dict_open: hash:./helo-control
rc=1
```

Comment: It's the HELO hostname `a7283cpov.earlywarning.com` that is rejected.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't my "helo-control" file cause it to be accepted?

Comment: It should. Yet it seems [reject_unknown_helo_hostname](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unknown_helo_hostname) last in the `smtpd_helo_restrictions` still causes rejection, looks like `check_helo_access` doesn't have any effect. Can you check your `ok-host-control` file explicitely with `postmap` command and that hostname? Can you add this particular name into that file and see if that helps? If so, there must be some problem with your `parent_domain_matches_subdomains` setting.

Comment: See the "UPDATE" section for the postmap results. It seems like the `.earlywarning.com` entry is not being properly used to resolve the "a7283cpov" subdomain. But yes, once I put the full `a7283cpov.earlywarning.com` string into `ok-host-control` and `helo-control`, it now works. So ... I guess this is the solution, although I don't understand why it was failing originally.

Comment: OOPS ... forgot to hit "Save".  The "UPDATE" section of my original question is now present. Not showing the results when adding the `a7283cpov.earlywarning.com` to both files, but it then indeed works in that case.

Comment: Could the following be the reason for the original failure: although `earlywarning.com` has a valid DNS A record, there is no A record for `a7283cpov.earlywarning.com` ... ???

Comment: I think what is surprising here is that `a7283cpov.earlywarning.com`, though it doesn't have a valid DNS record, should be covered by the `.earlywarning.com` part of the access table (that should match any subdomains).

Answer (score 2):

It is the HELO hostname `a7283cpov.earlywarning.com` that is rejected. The server gives a non-existent hostname as its HELO hostname.

Your attempt to whitelist it with `.earlywarning.com` in `check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo-control` fails, because `hash:` does not treat this as the wildcard you assume.

This could be done with [PCRE tables](https://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html), though. In Debian 11, you need to have the package `postfix-pcre` installed for the support for PCRE tables. Use `check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo-control` with file contents:

```
/(\.|^)earlywarning\.com$/   OK
```

Comment: `hash:` does not imply matching subdomains, but the `access` daemon is documented to lookup entries with a leading dot that way (not in the default postfix 3 configuration, though)

Answer (score 2):

The feature that you are trying to use with that leading dot `.domain.tld` syntax is not setup that way in the default Postfix installation.

If you want to use that, you could get the default value by calling `postconf -d parent_domain_matches_subdomains` and override that setting with one not including the `smtpd_access_maps` entry to have `check_helo_access` distinguish domains and subdomains. See [man 5 access](https://www.postfix.org/access.5.html), section *HOST NAME/ADDRESS PATTERNS*.

---

That file with both entries, with and without leading do, would match the helo name in question with or without that settings, but since you quote `postconf -f` as the command you used to update its lookup table.. you may not have successfully updated them yet. Try again using `postmap /path/to/ok-host-control`, then reload Postfix and look for warnings emitted on startup.